# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse throws OutOfMemory when memory is available

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, memory

The app with the issue is a windows service that runs on ~3000 machines and works fine for a large majority of them. However on ~20 machines it will periodically begin to fail with an unhandled OutOfMemory exception. If I have the customer reboot then the error goes away for a week (until memory usage get high again). The application itself does not use much memory and the call to GetResponse() that fails is tiny.

Here's the exact error message:

```
Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
```

and stack trace:

```
at System.Net.WinHttpWebProxyFinder.GetLastWin32Error()
at System.Net.WinHttpWebProxyFinder.GetProxies(Uri destination, Uri scriptLocation, String& proxyListString)
at System.Net.WinHttpWebProxyFinder.GetProxies(Uri destination, IList`1& proxyList)
at System.Net.HybridWebProxyFinder.GetProxies(Uri destination, IList`1& proxyList)
at System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine.GetProxies(Uri destination, IList`1& proxyList, Int32& syncStatus)
at System.Net.WebProxy.GetProxiesAuto(Uri destination, Int32& syncStatus)
at System.Net.ProxyScriptChain.GetNextProxy(Uri& proxy)
at System.Net.ProxyChain.ProxyEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint( Uri address, IWebProxy proxy, ProxyChain& chain, HttpAbortDelegate& abortDelegate, Int32& abortState)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.FindServicePoint(Boolean forceFind)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at ROS.RT.Client.Proxy.GetReponse(WebRequest req, Int32 tries)
at ROS.RT.Client.Proxy.GetCommands()
```

Here's the code that calls GetResponse():

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.ContentType = "application/json;";
req.Method = "GET";
var res = req.GetResponse();
```

I ran systeminfo at the time of last failure and it shows free memory

```
Total Physical Memory:     3,548 MB
Available Physical Memory: 1,144 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  7,397 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 2,227 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    5,170 MB
```

The application itself uses ~6MB of memory as far a I can tell. It doesn't appear to be getting that far but a typical response to the web request is ~1KB.

At this point I've told customers that something on their machine other than my app has a memory leak and it's causing my app to fail. However I don't fully understand what's happening here.

What would cause WinHttpWebProxyFinder.GetProxies to throw OutOfMemory when there is memory available?

Comment: It's very hard to make any assumptions based on your exception only without seeing some code. But I'll try. If your app is x86 - you may encounter 2 GB memory limit for your application, for example.

Comment: Do the ~20 machines crash with the same stack trace e.g. `System.Net.WinHttpWebProxyFinder.GetProxies()` is the last thing called before `GetLastWin32Error()`?

Comment: @Andy I've updated the post with code. I didn't include it originally because it's so trivial.

Comment: @JasonEvans - Yes all fail with the same stack trace.

Comment: The underlying error is a Windows error code, ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY.  Which doesn't necessarily mean that *your* program ran out of memory, the kernel's memory pools might be exhausted as well.  Not uncommonly caused by a buggy driver or another program that's leaking handles.  This is a job for IT staff to troubleshoot, unless they are willing to buy you a plane ticket.  Which you probably ought to turn down :)

Comment: Do you have many concurrent HTTP requests?  Are you ensuring you're disposing your `HttpWebResponse` object?  If the kernel side is running out of memory, this won't cause a GC cleanup that would otherwise clean up any unrooted `HttpWebResponse` objects and potentially reduce the stress on the kernel.